# How to add extra classes in body tag so that i will come only for the anonymous user?

Tags: theming

I want to add a extra unique class in body tag so that  it will come only for the anonymous user.

How to add it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add CSS class to body for admin-end](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71478/add-css-class-to-body-for-admin-end)

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97806/add-class-to-body-depending-on-role-of-author-of-user-page

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this is in a preprocess hook:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if (user_is_anonymous()) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'foo-class';
  }
}
```

Don't try to make this decision in a template file, you'll find it doesn't work properly when you have caching enabled. Or it'll break your caching entirely for the page.

Comment: In fact, core already uses this exact method in `template_preprocess_html` and either adds `logged-in` or `not-logged-in`, so a class should already be there.

Comment: Yep you're spot on @MPD, I just checked a few sites and they all have that class. Probably worth an answer actually

Answer (score 2):

Core already does this for you.  If you examine [includes/theme.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/7), you will find the implementation for [`template_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) which is run by default [before module and theme specific versions](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430).  In it is this code blip

```
function template_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // ...
  $variables['classes_array'][] = $variables['logged_in'] ? 'logged-in' : 'not-logged-in';
  // ...
}
```

So, there are already body classes, `logged-in` and `not-logged-in`, added for you.  If those classes is not there, something is altering the `$variables['classes_array']` in a naughty way.

Comment: @Vicky8888 - That's the right answer.